# How to rotate figure with caption

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, rotating, landscape

I have an image in landscape type; hence, I placed it by rotating it (angle = 90) to 90 degrees using a figure environment. However, I noticed the image caption is on the side but not at the bottom. I used a `landscape` environment; it worked well, but the image is placed on a new page, and the text hangs separately. I need to change the position of the caption in the figure environment. Help me with this problem.

```latex
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.83, angle = 90]{plate4/SAND allram.PNG}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure} 

\begin{landscape}   
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.83]{plate4/SAND allram.PNG}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}   
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

[image: Actual image I needed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hvfloat` package. You can see that is rotated both the figure and its caption into a text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{hvfloat}  % for rotating figure and caption

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]  

\hvFloat[floatPos=!ht,rotAngle=90,capWidth=w,capPos=b,capAngle=-360]{figure}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}%
}{Caption}{fig:enter-label}

\lipsum[3-5]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't this place the figure on a new page?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Now I see.

Comment: How is this better than just rotating the figure? This won't rotate the caption at all.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done! It it seems correct to me.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have understood that OP want rotate also the caption. See first figure with the red arrow.

Comment: It worked, thank you @Sebastiano

Comment: @vinothkumar You're welcome :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano  The code is functioning properly, however, only two images are placed between the text, while the other image is placed at the end.

Note: I'm working on overleaf

Comment: @vinothkumar You can change `floatPos=!ht`.

Answer (score 3):

You could place your image in a minipage rotate this minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And the other method is using the combination of `float.sty` and `rotating.sty` and the `MWE` is:

```
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
```

Comment: This will move the figure to a new page

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry,  understood the requirement wrongly, now updated, thanks for your review, happy new year 2024

Comment: @ MadyYuvi :thumbsup: :)