# How to rotate the figure and caption?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, rotating, landscape

I have an image in landscape type; hence, I placed it by rotating it (angle = 90) to 90 degrees using a figure environment. However, I noticed the image caption is on the side but not at the bottom. I used a landscape environment; it worked well, but the image is placed on a new page, and the text hangs separately. I need to change the position of the caption in the figure environment. Help me with this problem. I used the following code using the "hvFloat" package. But it worked well for the first two images (I have multiple images) after they were placed at the end of the document. I also need a "list of figures" commend to be worked for all the images. Kindly help me.

Note : I'm working in overleaf platform

```
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\hvFloat[floatPos=p, rotAngle=90,capWidth=w,capPos=b,capAngle=-360]{figure}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.83]{plate4/SANDY LOAM allram.PNG}%
}{SANDY LOAM}{fig:enter-label}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo even then, the text is hanging. I don't want the text to be hung separately.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, it is not duplication; that is a different approach.  There is a different problem specific to the above-mentioned code.

Comment: Being moved to the end of the document indicates an error of some sort, such as being too big for the page.

Comment: Every caption (third required argument?} will appear in the list of figures, unless an optional "short caption" is provided.

Comment: Isn't this an addendum to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706078/270231)? Why not ask there?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/graphics/rotex.pdf